# Bond graph, how to use it?

Tags: energy

Yesterday I heard the word "bond graph" and I felt like searching a bit about it.

From what I understood, it is a graph that links the flow of energy between "states" in multiphysics systems. I am not talking about the "bonds" as in chemistry or as in QM.

There are two variables associated with this graph: the "effort" and the "flow".

My questions are:

1. What is the definition of the "effort" and "flow"? I already know the list of the variables associated with each physics system, but I would like a more general definition.
2. How do we orient the arrows? I've never figured it out how the choice of arrows were made. I am unsure whether each "point" represents a state of transformation.
3. SF and SE stands for source of flow and source of effort. But what do they mean physically?
4. Are bond graphs used in engineering? In applied physics? I have seen most diagrams in thesis and "advanced" stuff like that and also in some mechanics papers. Is it used in fluid dynamics? Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD)? In turbulence study?

I didn't find any related thread on PSE, please tell me if you find a related thread.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bond graphing (also called *power bond graphing*) is a prescription for turning a physical system into something that looks like a circuit diagram, and then provides a simple method for deriving the differential equations of motion for that system. For an nth-order system it yields n first-order partial differential equations in matrix form, which can then be inverted by hand or by computer to solve them. Programs for directly solving power bond graphs are available.

All types of dynamical systems in the bond graph paradigm transfer power between elements by means of what are called effort and flow variables. Examples of effort variables are voltage (in electrical systems), pressure (in hydraulic systems) and force (in mechanical systems); examples of the corresponding flow variables are then current, flow rate, and velocity. Taking proper care of units, the product of an effort variable times a flow variable is always power, as for example voltage x current = watts, force x velocity = horsepower, etc.

The arrows in a bond graph represent the direction of power flow from the sources to the elements in the model. The nodes where linkages occur between elements in the graph represent either parallel connections or series connections between those elements. A parallel connection is characterized by a common effort and a flow which is divided between the connected elements and is called an O-junction; a series connection is the dual of this, in which  a common flow is asserted and the effort is divided between the connected elements and is called a 1-junction.

The elements in the graph represent lumped parameters of inertance, compliance, and resistance.

SE represents an *effort source* of which an example would be a voltage supply in a circuit. SF represents a *flow source* of which an examples would be a positive-displacement oil pump in a hydraulic system.

Power bond graphs are typically used by mechanical engineers to model complex dynamical systems including machines, hydraulics, electrical circuits and heat transfer problems. They provide a straightforward means for deriving the feedback control algorithms needed to force the system to assume and maintain a desired state. By making the constituitive equations of the system components contained within the model either nonlinear or time-dependent, fully nonlinear systems can readily be solved within the bond graph paradigm.

The standard work which describes power bond graphs and how they are used is *System Dynamics, A Unified Approach* by Karnopp and Rosenberg.

Comment: Wow, that is a very complete answer. Thank you for your detailed explanation. Do you have a software to design bond graphs/power bond graphs? Or do you use vectorial drawing/LateX to do it?

Comment: I was a bond graphing expert in grad school but that was 40 years ago! I don't know anything about how it is used today, sorry. I was lucky enough to take classes from Karnopp himself though.